# CSS Triangle that stretches 100% of the document

Tags: css, html

So here is the triangle:

```
#header-triangle-right {
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    top:0px;
    right:0;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 400px solid transparent;
    border-right: 1000px solid #000000;
}
```

So how do I make this triangle stretch 100% of the document since 'border' does not support percentages?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any pure CSS way to do this, but if you're okay with using jQuery you could do something like this:

```
var windowWidth  = $(window).width(),
    windowHeight = $(window).height();

$('#header-triangle-right').css({
    'border-top'   : windowHeight + 'px solid transparent',
    'border-right' : windowWidth + 'px solid  #000'
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TzM5m/